# Accessing data from collectionB within a map/reduce performed on collectionA

Tags: mongodb, database

How can I access data from collectionB within the "map" part of a map/reduce being performed on collectionA?

If it helps, I have phrases stored in collectionA which I want to split each phrase into individual words within the map, and then grab specific values for each word from collectionB.

In code, I imagined it would look something like this…

```
map = function() {
    var key, value;
    var results = db["collectionB"].find({something_related_to_collectionA});

    results.forEach(function(result) {
        // Change the value
    });

    emit(key, value);
};
reduce = function(key, values) {
    // Perform the reduce
};
db["collectionA"].mapReduce(map, reduce, {out: "collectionC"});
```

Answer (score 1):

So, in theory this should work. In practice though, you don't want to do this.

This type of lookup opens up a whole can of worms. For example how does this work with sharding? Imagine that your javascript is on `shard2` and it's trying to access data from `shard1`, how does that work? `shard2` doesn't even know that `shard1` exists.

If you look at your code, you're fundamentally trying to re-create a `JOIN` statement. One of the premises for MongoDB's scalability is that it avoids joins b/c joins don't scale horizontally.

This may mean some more de-normalization or some form of pre-processing or some other system change. Ideally if you need to perform map-reduces on a collection, you'll design that collection to contain all of the data needed to perform this operation.

Answer (score 0):

That should work fine.

`db` is accessible from pretty much anywhere as far as I can tell. I've ran a (quite useless) test and it worked pretty much as I'd expected. What problems are you having?